# IndexedDBShim.js error : JavaScript runtime error: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexeddb, shim

I am experimenting with IndexedDB jquery API as indexedDB isnt compatible with safari / ipad. Ive just started using it and got this error when only running HTML and im not able to use anything in the files.
The files im refering to are [IndexedDBShim](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/index.html)

my html looks like

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="JavaScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/IndexedDBShim.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/IndexedDBShim.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.indexeddb.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.indexeddb.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="test()">CREATE DATABASE</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And there is nothing in the Test() function.
The error im getting is:
**0x800a13b5 - JavaScript runtime error: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode**
on line 1653 at window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.oIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

Am i using this wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you've encountered this issue: https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim/pull/72

Comment: @RoryKoehein thanks for your reply, your right but i dont seem to have that file included althought i do have it in a zip file i downloaded from the site. Now im convinced im doing something wrong. I also havent installed grunt cos im not sure how to, not sure if thats important for this either

Comment: You wouldn't have that file, it's a source file which is built to `IndexedDBShim.js` which is then minified to `IndexedDBShim.min.js`. Which does mean you are including both `IndexedDBShim` and `jquery.indexeddb` twice (built file and minified file).

Comment: The easiest solution is to comment out `'use strict'` in `IndexedDBShim.js` until they have fixed this (merged the pull request I mentioned)

Comment: @RoryKoehein oh right, so assuming i want to change my globalVars.js file, how would i build this to make a new IndexedDBShim.js

Comment: @RoryKoehein u mean the 'use strict' in the IndexedDBShim.js? cos i tried that and the error remained

Comment: Have you now got one single version of the shim and the jquery plugin? And there is no `'use strict'` in any of those files? The github page describes how to build: https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim

Comment: made sure, ran it and now error "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined" in file "jquery.indexeddb.js"

Comment: Well you need to include jquery (http://jquery.com) to be able to use jQuery plugins ;)

Comment: @RoryKoehein thank you so much for your help so far. Its all working fine now. All scripts taken out, jquery mobile scripts included, thanks. Just another quick questions. I need to test that a database is being created on safari and/or ipad. I do I know the databases are being created and my code is working? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the line anymore:

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.oIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
```

In all browsers the keyword `indexedDB` is now a standard http://caniuse.com/#search=IndexedDB.